# Finding # of combinations of truth values

Tags: java, boolean, expression, combinations

There is a question I have had a problem doing.

How many combinations of truth values for p, q, and r make this expression true?
(p && !q) || (q || !r)

I know that the answer is 7, but I don't know how they got the answer. I could simply test every combination (8 is max, 2^3), but is there a faster way I can do this? Can the expression be simplified?

Comment: Thanks, I also forgot to note that I wasn't suppose to be creating a program. I was studying for a competitive computer science test and this was a question that I had trouble doing in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly does not need an exhaustive search. You can reason as follows:

1. Due to the `|| !r` you know that the 4 combinations with `r == false` satisfy the expression
2. Due to the `|| q` you know that of the remaining 4 combinations, the 2 with `q == true` satisfy the expression
3. Due to the `(p && !q)` you know that of the remaining 2 combinations both have `q == false` (because you've already considered the cases where `q == true` above) and so the 1 with `p == true` satisfies the expression

Adding those up you have 7 combinations satisfying the expression.

As for simplifying the expression, `(p && !q) || q` is equivalent to `p || q`. So the expression can be simplified to `p || q || !r`. That can also be expressed as `!(!p && !q && r)` which makes it obvious why there are 7 combinations: there's only one combination that does not satisfy the expression.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question, "can it be simplified?":  In Boolean algebra, the expression

```
a || (!a && b)
```

is equivalent to

```
a || b
```

Looking at the original expression:

```
(p && !q) || (q || !r)
```

note that `||` is associative (and so is `&&`), and therefore you can rearrange the parentheses:

```
((p && !q) || q) || !r
```

and the first part is a case of the equivalence at the top of my answer, thus

```
((p && !q) || q)
```

is equivalent to

```
p || q
```

(note that `||` and `&&` are both commutative), so the whole expression is equivalent to

```
p || q || !r
```